# What is the most efficient way to implement a C hash table with timeout on entries?

Tags: c, linux, timer, timeout, hashtable

I am currently developing a hash table to serve as a database data structure which may contain a large number of elements and which must be as much efficient as possible (especially on the operations to add a new elements and update an existing element).
I am also forced to use only C (avoiding C++ or other languages which have existing classes or structures which could really help in this case).

What I need to develop is a hash table with linked lists in which each entry has a timeout (let's say few minutes), after which it should automatically delete itself (or, as an alternative, the old entries should be "garbage collected" at a certain point in time, as elements may be added at a very fast rate and I do not want to use too much memory for entries which are too old).

I was thinking about adding a timer field to each entry of the Hash Table:

```
struct HTnode {
    // Hash table entry ID
    long int id;
    
    // Pointer to the next element of the linked list (when hash is the same for two different IDs)
    struct STnode * next;
    
    // Other fields...

    // Timer for each entry
    timer_t entryTimer;
};
```

Then, when a new entry is added, to start a timer (this project will only run on Linux, that's why I am considering to use `timer_t` - error checking is not performed in this sample code for the sake of brevity):

```
struct sigevent entryTimerEvent;
struct itimerspec entryTimerTs;

// Allocate a new entry for a given id (struct HTnode *entry)
// ...

memset(&entryTimerEvent,0,sizeof(entryTimerEvent));

// entryDeleter() is a function deleting the current entry from the hash table
entryTimerEvent.sigev_notify_function=entryDeleter;
entryTimerEvent.sigev_notify=SIGEV_THREAD;

entryTimerTs.it_value.tv_sec=...; // Set to a certain timeout value
entryTimerTs.it_value.tv_nsec=...; // Set to a certain timeout value
entryTimerTs.it_interval.tv_sec=...; // Set to a certain timeout value
entryTimerTs.it_interval.tv_nsec=...; // Set to a certain timeout value

timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,&entryTimerEvent,&(entry->entryTimer));

timer_settime(entry->entryTimer,0,&entryTimerTs,NULL);
```

When an entry is updated, instead, I would just rearm the timer with `timer_settime`.

However, I fear that a solution like this could become problematic in terms of performance when I reach more than some thousands of entries, all with their own running timer (some active entries may be even updated with a sub-second granularity, causing very frequent calls to `timer_settime`), and I am currently struggling to find a good alternative.

Are there better and more efficient solutions, in your opinion, maybe not requiring the usage of timers for each entry?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why not just consider the timestamp when you lookup an element or add a new one (you could overwrite an expired element in-place)? You don't need to remove something so long as you can tell it is invalid.

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete the oldest rather than the least recently used (LRU)?

Comment: BTW: there is a hashtable +LRU-chain in the IP-stack implementation, for the timeouts. You could check the linux kernel source.

Comment: Correction: the timers belong to the TCP state-machine.

Comment: @IanAbbott Sorry for the very late reply, but I had to temporarily freeze this project, and I could start it again only few days ago. Actually the goal would be to delete entries which has not been updated (not read, but updated) in the last M minutes. So, it would be more like deleting the oldest than the Least Recently Used. The solution of having a separate thread for "garbage collecting" the oldest entries seems to be surely a solution to try out (I would then need to test how this can impact the performance of the whole application).

Answer (score 1):

What I understand of you requirements:

1. If an element has timed-out, it should not appear when you try to get it
2. Eventually It will be deleted so that the table do not grow forever

To implement that you can add a timestamp with each element and

1. Change your get function to check if the current time is before the timestamp, otherwise, do not return it
2. Have a watcher thread that delete expired elements

Answer (score 1):

A crude but easy option:

Have distinct hash tables - e.g. three tables each storing all entries added during a particular minute; you add new entries into table[active].  To do a lookup or erase, search in the active table (if recently added elements are statistically most likely to be accessed), then try older tables in turn.  When you add an element and find the minute has changed, shift active along with `++active %= 3` then clear `table[active]` before adding the new element to it.

---

A more over-engineered way, with a single hash table...

Assuming you want elements older than X units of time to be erased even if they've been accessed recently, then all you need is a double-ended queue off to the side of the hash table that tracks the elements you've added.  Each element in the queue should store the expiry time and whatever's convenient for quick deletion (e.g. a pointer to the previous element (or bucket/root) in the linked list from the bucket, if you're using separate chaining, don't have to support resizing of the hash table, and know elements won't be erased by any other mechanism).  I say previous because if it's a singly-linked list then you'll need to rewire the previous element's next pointer.  If it's a doubly-linked list, it may be more intuitive to store a pointer to the element itself, then you can use `prev->next = next` to rewire.

When you add an element you add it to the back of that queue.  Whenever you've idle time for some housekeeping, you start at the front of the queue and erase however-many elements are expired.  You can see whether it's better to have a separate thread handling expiries (but then you need locking around the hash table accesses/updates), or do it from the same thread that otherwise using the hash table.

If you do want recently-accessed elements to hang around longer, then you'd want to use a Least Recently Used cache mechanism to track the expiry times, and that means you need to be able to search in the LRU by key, so you'd might want to use a balanced binary tree.  This will be a lot more implementation effort.

If you're using a closed hashing / open addressing hash table, what to do to erase elements will depend on how you're handling collisions: you might be able to just overwrite the bucket with a no-longer-in-use sentinel value, or you might be obliged to shift another element to be closer to its hashed-to bucket.  These kind of factors may change what indexing data store in the timeout-tracking double-ended queue or LRU.

It is a major undertaking to do it from scratch in C, so I'd suggest you utilise existing libraries of data structures.  Still, asking for recommendations for 3rd party resources is off topic on StackOverflow, which may frustrate that if you don't already know your options.  I couldn't go back from C++ to C these days - too frustrating - and I'm not aware of current offerings to suggest something....

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply and comment and thank you very much for the suggestions. 
As I said in another comment, I had to temporarily freeze this project, and I could start it again only few days ago.

The idea of using a double-ended queue is very interesting. The issue I see, however, would be the update operations. 
In fact, my database will be interested by a lot of frequent updates, following an initial insert operation, which, at a certain moment in time, may stop, making the entry obsolete (at which point the entry would need to be deleted).

Comment: All these frequent updates may impact performance as the queue would need to be "rearranged", for each update, moving the last updated element from its current position again at the back of the queue.
Considering the cost for "scanning" the queue to find the elements to be updated, wouldn't be more convenient, in the end, to just have a separate thread scanning the whole active elements of the hash table from time to time and deleting the oldest ones? 
Are there other better solutions in your opinion, considering these frequent updates?

Comment: Or, maybe, could it be a good idea to use X hash tables, as you suggested at the beginning, moving then the entries inside them (with delete->insert operations and only if needed) when an update occurs? 

This would require, if I'm not wrong, to look for the entry to update in X hash tables (with O(X) complexity), which could be probably less performance-impacting than scanning, in the worst case, the whole queue, containing N>X elements, with O(N) complexity.